# Multiple Google maps based on user input

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I suspect I'm doing it all wrong but I have no idea how to realize this.

User can add extra fields (locations) in a form, behind each field (location) is a button that opens a modal containing a Google map where you can select a location.

[image]

The problem I'm running into is, the current code is for one location.

User can add multiple locations with 'onlick' but i only have this piece for my google map.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var geocoder1 = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var marker1 = null;
var map1 = null;
function initialize1() {
      var $latitude = document.getElementById('latitude');
      var $longitude = document.getElementById('longitude');
      var latitude = 51.21325734558688
      var longitude = 4.452420938900765;
      var zoom = 16;

      var LatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);

      var mapOptions = {
        zoom: zoom,
        center: LatLng,
        panControl: false,
        zoomControl: false,
        scaleControl: true,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      }

      map1 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
      if (marker1 && marker1.getMap) marker1.setMap(map1);
      marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: LatLng,
        map: map1,
        title: 'Drag Me!',
        draggable: true
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'dragend', function(marker1) {
        var latLng = marker1.latLng;
        $latitude.value = latLng.lat();
        $longitude.value = latLng.lng();
      });


    }
    initialize1();
    $('#findbutton').click(function (e) {
        var address = $("#Postcode").val();
        geocoder1.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                map1.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                marker1.setPosition(results[0].geometry.location);
                $(latitude).val(marker1.getPosition().lat());
                $(longitude).val(marker1.getPosition().lng());
            } else {
                alert("Geocode is mislukt met volgende fout: " + status);
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
</script>
```

If the user wants to add 5 locations, there should also be 5 modals containing a Google map.

I do not expect ready-made solutions but tips or advice on how to approach this.

I already thought to add extra javascript to the onlick action of the button but that doesn't work.
Apparently it is not possible to add extra javascript code via jquery, for example.
==> https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_dom_add.asp

Comment: You want to dynamically generate Google Maps map view instances in new modals per use input? just to clarify;

Comment: Yes, when the user add a new location (traject option in the form) there should be added new code for a new modal en a new Google map https://jsfiddle.net/po1x9Lrh/